# AJAX.NET Subscribe to Reorderlist ItemCommand or DeleteCommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, ajax.net, reorderlist

I would like to subscribe to the ItemCommand event of a Reorderlist I have on my page.  The front end looks like this...

```
<cc1:ReorderList id="ReorderList1" runat="server" CssClass="Sortables" Width="400"  OnItemReorder="ReorderList1_ItemReorder" OnItemCommand="ReorderList1_ItemCommand">
...
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="delete.jpg" CommandName="delete" CssClass="playClip" />
...
</cc1:ReorderList>
```

in the back-end I have this on Page_Load

```
ReorderList1.ItemCommand += new EventHandler<AjaxControlToolkit.ReorderListCommandEventArgs>(ReorderList1_ItemCommand);
```

and this function defined

```
protected void ReorderList1_ItemCommand(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.ReorderListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "delete")
            {
                //do something here that deletes the list item
            }
        }
    }
```

Despite my best efforts though, I can't seem to get this event to fire off.  How do you properly subscribe to this events in a ReorderList control?

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
<cc2:ReorderList ID="rlEvents" runat="server" AllowReorder="True" CssClass="reorderList"
        DataKeyField="EventId" DataSourceID="odsEvents" PostBackOnReorder="False"
        SortOrderField="EventOrder" OnDeleteCommand="rlEvents_DeleteCommand">
...
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDeleteEvent" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EventId") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" />
...
</cc2:ReorderList>
```

code behind:

```
protected void rlEvents_DeleteCommand(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.ReorderListCommandEventArgs e)
{
   // delete the item
   // this will give you the DataKeyField for the current record -> int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
   //rebind the ReorderList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your ImageButton's `CommandName="delete"` you should be hooking up to the DeleteCommand event instead of ItemCommand.